# Google cloud storage integration in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing an iPhone Application where I want to integrate google cloud storage so that I can store images. Please anyone can help me or provide me the link of sample. I tried searching but could not find.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using the [Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/). It uses the [JSON API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/). You will need to enable the JSON API by visiting the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console), clicking APIs, and enabling the "Google Cloud Storage JSON API"

Answer (score -1):

There is no specific library or sdk for Cloud integration but there is a web based interface you can integrate for google cloud. you'll have to read about it a little. here's the link

https://developers.google.com/storage/